# Compliance of .eu domain names post-Brexit

Tags: international, european-union, corporate-law, domain-name, brexit

I am a sole-trader who operates purely in the UK, and I also have a corresponding (dormant) Limited company on 'Companies House'. I have both .com and .co.uk suffixes. I also have .eu suffix, and would like to continue to protect it post-Brexit, as I do not want others taking advantage of my lack of cross-border priveleges and 'piggyback' my business name (which is same as my domain prefix). Up to now I do not have any direct links to the EU27.

As things currently stand, the EU plan to uni-laterally revoke .eu domain suffixes from non-eligible people/organizations. One possible option to protect the domain would be to set up a (dormant) limited company in Estonia, Rep. Ireland or any other low-cost but reliable member state. What significant obligations would accompany this? Are there any other inexpensive ways to protect the .eu domain name?

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option of a trustee service. [Here](https://www.internetx.com/en/news-detailview/domains-under-eu-for-uk-a-brexit-update/), they write:

> Requirements for the .eu trustee service:
>
> - Postal address in the respective country of registration for the    AdminC (administrative contact) or the OwnerC (owner contact)
> - Legal agreement with a trustee service provider, e.g. the registrar
> - Local contact person for the domain
>
> The customer is the owner of the domain, the trustee service provider
> is specified as the    administrative partner (AdminC).

Deadline to act seems to be Dec. 31, 2020. A trustee service might be easier and cheaper than setting up a Ltd somewhere inside the EU.